# Creating Xml file using Android

Tags: android

I tried this code but i don't know where I will find the xml file created

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //create a new file called "new.xml" in the SD card
    File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/new.xml");
    try{
        newxmlfile.createNewFile();
    }catch(IOException e){
        Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");
    }
    FileOutputStream fileos = null;         
    try{
        fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");
    }

    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    try {

        serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");

        serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true)); 

        serializer.setFeature
 ("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true); 

        serializer.startTag(null, "root"); 

            serializer.startTag(null, "child1");
            serializer.endTag(null, "child1");

            serializer.startTag(null, "child2");

            serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
            serializer.endTag(null, "child2");

            serializer.startTag(null, "child3");
            //write some text inside <child3>
            serializer.text("some text inside child3");
            serializer.endTag(null, "child3");

        serializer.endTag(null, "root");
        serializer.endDocument();
        serializer.flush();
        fileos.close();

           TextView tv = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.result);
           tv.setText("file has been created on SD card");
           System.out.println("file created");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception","error occurred while creating xml file");
    }
   }
   }
```

Comment: It shold be in sdcard/new.xml.
See: [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

It differs with the model of the phone, and also if you are having any external storage.
Best way to check the path of file is to do it in your app. You should use:

```
String path = newxmlfile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

the file must be created in the sdcard if you don't find it then there is a problem in the code

Comment: i found it finally :) thkx for all